# When i run ionic 3 program i get Property 'push' is missing in type 'FirebaseObjectObservable and Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

Please help me fix the error

```
Type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<ShoppingItem>'. Property 'push' is missing in type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any>'.
```

in the code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
import { ShoppingItem } from '../../models/shopping-items/shopping-item.interface';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-edit-shopping-item',
  templateUrl: 'edit-shopping-item.html',
})
export class EditShoppingItemPage {

  shoppingItemSubscription: Subscription;
  shoppingItemRef$: FirebaseListObservable<ShoppingItem>;
  shoppingItem = {} as ShoppingItem;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {

    const shoppingItemId = this.navParams.get('shoppingItemId');
    this.shoppingItemRef$ = this.database.object(`shopping-list/${shoppingItemId}`);
    this.shoppingItemSubscription = this.shoppingItemRef$.subscribe(shoppingItem => this.shoppingItem = shoppingItem);

  }

  editshoppingitem(shoppingItem:ShoppingItem){
    this.shoppingItemRef$.update(shoppingItem);
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

ionViewWillLeave(){

  this.shoppingItemSubscription.unsubscribe();


}
```